# How to show full processlist in mysql with state higher than x?

Tags: mysql, bash, command-line

I'm writing a "systems check" bash script and for one of the items, I want to check all running processes in MySQL, but I only care if they have a state higher than 30.

In MySQL, is there a way to show a list of processes only that have a state higher than x, such as over 30?

I tried `show processlist where state>=30;`

I have version 5.5.58-0+deb8u1.

Answer (score 2):

As @Hariraman Radhakrishnan answered, the `SHOW PROCESSLIST` command cannot be modified.

However, from reading his link, the `SHOW PROCESSLIST` actually reads from `information_schema.processlist`

This means you can perform a normal query against `information_schema.processlist` like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.processlist 
WHERE TIME > 30
```

If you look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/processlist-table.html, you can see what each column means.

I have written the query to select all processes that have been running for more than 30 seconds, but that might also just be a sleeping connection, for example a program that connects at the beginning, and then keeps the connection alive until you close the program again.

This would mean that the process can run for minutes, hours or days, but will have `COMMAND = 'Sleep'` most of the time.

If you only want to see long running queries, you should update your queries to:
`SELECT * FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE COMMAND != 'Sleep' AND TIME > 30;`

TIME is reset when the state changes

From the docs: "The time in seconds that the thread has been in its current state.")

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, SHOW PROCESSLIST does not allow filtering. When you are on MySQL ≥ 5.1.7, do this instead:

`SELECT * FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE command != 'Sleep' ORDER BY id;`

That also allows you to only show some values or order differently, like so:

`SELECT user, time, state, info FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE command != 'Sleep' ORDER BY time DESC, id;`

One more example -- see all non-sleeping queries that take some time, for example at least 2 seconds:

`SELECT user, time, state, info FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE command != 'Sleep' AND time >= 2 ORDER BY time DESC, id;`

Comment: For my sake and anyone else this is helpful to, can you improve your answer by listing the command I should use here and also explain how sleeping relates to state? Thanks.